# How does the menu bar in xaml resizes itself?

Tags: c#, xaml

How can I make the menu bar in the WPF Application's xaml file to resize itself automatically if I maximize or minimize the window?

Here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="Interface.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Physiosoft" Height="750" Width="1100">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1088" MinHeight="23" MinWidth="1088">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Save                     Ctrl + S" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Help">
            <MenuItem Header="About Physiosoft                                F1" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use it inside a [DockPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx) with its property of docking to fill ([by, precisely not setting it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750624.aspx)) or within a [Grid](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx&ei=XbBOUKGXJOPt0gGAl4DADA&usg=AFQjCNGC4ZxJdgKJY9NNL4uEXTExRi7-jw&sig2=lx_FP10u6vUQAz4w4_-Q4g) column/row whose width/height is set to `*` so it will auto resize to the available space.

This, as example, will create a three column layout with a main panel and a resizable menu, use it as an start point:

```
<Window x:Class="Interface.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Physiosoft" Height="750" Width="1100">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1"  Name="menu1">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Save                     Ctrl + S" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Help">
            <MenuItem Header="About Physiosoft                                F1" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am not able to put * as a value of width. I am already using it inside a grid though.

Comment: @Reaper211 It doesn't matter if you're using it inside. Then the problem must be another one. Put your code to see and analyze.

Comment: Somehow it still won't resize the menu bar automatically but it did make it move to right when I maximize the window.

Comment: @Reaper211 Fixed. Your problem is that you were also setting its width, height, horizontalalignment and verticalalignment. You can't set those values if you're trying to get them automatically set for you because you're just overriding those values.

Comment: Thank you. Though i still had to mention the height as I was trying to manage the width! :)

Comment: @Reaper211 Glad it works. I will to encourage you to NOT DO THAT! Set it to auto it will fill until its proper content size. Those way you'll ensure a nicely scalable UI given not only different resolutions but also DPI configurations.